# Can't change `extern char` identifier from GNU example code?

Tags: c, glibc

[GNU.org](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Variable-Arguments-Output.html) provides this example function for printing an error message:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void
eprintf (const char *template, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  extern char *program_invocation_short_name;

  fprintf (stderr, "%s: ", program_invocation_short_name);
  va_start (ap, template);
  vfprintf (stderr, template, ap);
  va_end (ap);
}

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    eprintf ("Teste %i\n", 12);
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't really get it. How come I can't change `program_invocation_short_name` to (e.g.) `banana`? As in

```c
extern char *banana;
```

#### Result is I get this output:

GCC:

```
$ gcc -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    eprint.c -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o eprint

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZLCXcL.o: warning: relocation against `bananas' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZLCXcL.o: in function `eprintf':
/home/username/Projects/c/lib/eprint.c:10: undefined reference to `bananas'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: eprint] Error 1
```

Clang:

```
clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    eprint.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o eprint
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/eprint-8fa7ad.o: in function `eprintf':
/home/mitsuki/Projects/c/lib/eprint.c:10: undefined reference to `bananas'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [<builtin>: eprint] Error 1
```

Comment: That's because [program_invocation_short_name](https://linux.die.net/man/3/program_invocation_short_name) is defined whereas `banana` is something you made up that is not defined anywhere.

Comment: `program_invocation_short_name` is provided by glibc - see https://linux.die.net/man/3/program_invocation_short_name

Comment: The statement `extern char *program_invocation_short_name;` is a declaration. It tells the compiler that the variable `program_invocation_short_name`exists (is defined) *somewhere*. If you declare and use a variable which doesn't actually exists anywhere (like the case with `extern char *banana;`) then you will get linker errors shown in the question.

Comment: Oh, thank you much, guys.

Answer (score 2):

When you write an `extern` declaration, you're telling the compiler that another file defined a variable with that name and type, and you want to be able to use it in this file. The linker will then match up the two uses of the same name and make them refer to the same actual variable. If you `extern` something that *hasn't* been defined somewhere else, you get an error from the linker (`ld`) which basically says "hey, you promised me that this would get defined somewhere, but it never did! I can't make a working program out of this."